# Iphone 6: position fixed scrolling issue

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone-6

I have similar issue as mentioned in this question [New Fixed position bug on iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391059/new-fixed-position-bug-on-ios8).

If your click on menu which has submenu then menu expands to all li's height. It works fine everywhere except iphone 6 plus. In iphone 6 plus if you click on last menu which has submenus it expands and user can not scroll.

For nav i have used position:fixed. How to make it scroll?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: @Shaggy http://jsbin.com/xuyevi/2/ something like this but if u click on menu and if it has submenus it expands

Comment: So, what you're saying is that, because the menu is fixed, the last submenu drops off the bottom of the screen?

Comment: yes because i tried adding margin-bottom padding bottom to the menu options but still it is not scrolling

Comment: See answer below, should help you out. Apologies for the lack of example code, I'm on my phone at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set the height or max-height of the fixed element to 100% and then set its overflow to auto. This will allow you to scroll the menu, independently of the rest of the page, if its overall height exceeds the height of the window.